# Hibernate single-table inheritance and multiple @ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have the following class setup, with SINGLE_TABLE inheritance:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANIMALS")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISCR")
@DiscriminatorValue("Animal")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Animal {
    private String discr;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ANIMALS")
@DiscriminatorValue("Cat")
public class Cat extends Animal {
    private String discr;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONS")
public class Person {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ANIMAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Animal animal;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ANIMAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Cat cat;
    ...
}
```

In the `Person` class, I have two `@ManyToOne` relationships to the `Animal` and `Cat` classes. I'd like Hibernate to map to the correct field (`animal` or `cat`) according to the discriminator. With this code, Hibernate throws errors when trying to map an `Animal` record to a `Cat` object.

Comment: Huh? So a Person has an "animal" __and__ a Cat?! So a person can have a Cat and a Dog ? Makes no sense to map the same "FK". Suggest you go back to O-O modelling basics and decide what you're trying to represent here, because any ORM has total justification in throwing an exception at that!

Comment: One or the other. The FK maps to the same table and I just want Hibernate to map to one of the 2 fields, according to the discriminator

Comment: If a Person has one animal of some type or other, then the correct O-O way to model that is a SINGLE 1-1/N-1 relation, and you handle whether something is Cat or other in your accessor methods. You don't do weird stuff with the underlying data

Comment: The model is correct, like you describe. I just wanted Hibernate to handle the mapping so that, for example, I can use the field cat in a query instead of having a condition with the discriminator.